# Pagination is not working in php and mysql

Tags: php, jquery, html

Here I am going to paginate `chapter_subscriptions` table which has many rows. So I am trying to paginate in such a way that at a time 10 rows will be displayed. My problem is when I click the insert button, the `page` variable in the jQuery code isn't assigned a value and stays `undefined`. Then the sql query in `chapter_subscription_searchpagination.php` fails. I can't figure out where I've made a mistake.

**chapter_subscription_search.php**

```
<?php
  include('db.php');
  $start_date=date("Y-m-d");
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chapter Subscriptions</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <img src="images/ipoint.png" class="logo" /> USER REGISTRATION</header>
      <div class="container">
        <h1 style="text-align:center">ADDING THE CHAPTER SUBSCRIPTION DETAILS</h1>
        <form name="chapter_subscriptions" id="chapter_subscriptions" action="#" method="post">

          <?php
          $end_date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 months"));
          $end_date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+6 months"));
          $end_date3 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+9 months"));
          ?>

          <table align='center' border='1'>
            <tr>            
              <td>
                <label for="userid">UserId</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input id="userid" name="userid"  type="text" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="chapter_no">ChapterNumber</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input id="chapter_no" name="chapter_no" type="text"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="start_date">StartDate</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input id="start_date" name="start_date" type="text"/>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="end_date">EndDate</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <select name="end_date" id="end_date">
                <option value=<?php echo $end_date1; ?>><?php echo $end_date1; ?></option>
                <option value=<?php echo $end_date2; ?>><?php echo $end_date2; ?> </option>
                <option value=<?php echo $end_date3;?>><?php echo $end_date3;?> </option>

              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <div id="wrap">
          <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="insert">
          <input type="submit" name="edit" id="edit" value="edit">
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#insert").click(function(e){     
          var userid = $("#userid").val();
          var chapter_no = $("#chapter_no").val();
          var start_date = $("#start_date ").val();
          var end_date = $("#end_date").val();
          var page = $("#page").val();
          alert(page);
        });
      });
    </script>

    <div id="display"></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the code in `chapter_subscription_searchpagination.php`?

Comment: I sent right....

Comment: Instead of complex logic, can you simply do a `<?php var_dump($_REQUEST); ?>` in your `chapter_subscription_searchpagination.php` and see what your `$.ajax` got?

Comment: in which line i need to add this

Comment: Simply replace the whole file content with this one line (you may want to backup first).

Comment: i get like this array(5) { ["userid"]=> string(4) "1006" ["chapter_no"]=> string(1) "2" ["start_date"]=> string(10) "2017-03-20" ["end_date"]=> string(10) "2017-06-20" ["page"]=> string(9) "undefined" }

Comment: Your "page", when submitted to `chapter_subscription_searchpagination.php`, is already "undefined". Probably because your `#page` value is not properly initialized.

Comment: Can you retry with `<input type="hidden" name="page" id="page" value="<?php if(isset($page)) echo $page;?>">` modified as `<input type="hidden" name="page" id="page" value="<?php echo isset($page) ? $page : 1;?>">`

Comment: why cant you use a plugin such as datatable or bootstrap table to save you the hassels?? They already have a working pagination module plus exporting to excel or pdf or even print.

Comment: Fixed spelling/grammar mistakes; Removed tags; Formatted code so it's readable. Removed code which doesn't have anything to do with the error/question but only obfuscated the question.